# Scatter plot with colored markers + colormap in ECharts

Tags: echarts

After reading the ECharts documentation and looking at examples, I haven't found anything that would allow coloring scatter plot markers automatically according to a continuous data dimension.

Basically, I'm trying to plot something like this:

[image]

What would be the right approach to that problem in ECharts?

---

For example modifying the [basic scatter plot example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-simple) to use a scalar `color` for all data points is possible as follows:

```js
option = {
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [10.0, 8.04],
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [13.0, 7.58],
            [9.0, 8.81],
            [11.0, 8.33],
            [14.0, 9.96],
            [6.0, 7.24],
            [4.0, 4.26],
            [12.0, 10.84],
            [7.0, 4.82],
            [5.0, 5.68]
        ],
        color: '#F00',
        type: 'scatter'
    }]
};
```

What I would like to achieve is to pass in a data vector like this for the `color`, which doesn't work:

```js
option = {
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [10.0, 8.04],
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [13.0, 7.58],
            [9.0, 8.81],
            [11.0, 8.33],
            [14.0, 9.96],
            [6.0, 7.24],
            [4.0, 4.26],
            [12.0, 10.84],
            [7.0, 4.82],
            [5.0, 5.68]
        ],
        color: [
            0.11,
            0.53,
            0.76,
            0.01,
            0.53,
            0.19,
            0.64,
            0.65,
            0.34,
            0.23,
            0.81
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    }]
};
```

The only solution I see is:

- computing the colors from the data manually,
- using sequences of only length 1 to have control over the color of each scatter point.

Is there a mechanism in ECharts that simplifies this process?

Comment: Note: this question is [being discussed on the meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386369/is-asking-for-how-to-improve-the-question-a-reason-to-delete-a-comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the visualmap's dimension property

```
options: EChartOption = {
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    visualMap: [
        {
            type: 'continuous',
            dimension: 2,
            orient: 'vertical',
            right: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            text: ['HIGH', 'LOW'],
            calculable: true,
            inRange: {
                color: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']
            }
        }
    ],
    series: [{
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [10.0, 8.04, 0],
            [8.0, 6.95, 0.1],
            [13.0, 7.58, 0.2],
            [9.0, 8.81, 0.3],
            [11.0, 8.33, 0.4],
            [14.0, 9.96, 0.5],
            [6.0, 7.24, 0.6],
            [4.0, 4.26, 0.7],
            [12.0, 10.84, 0.8],
            [7.0, 4.82, 0.9],
            [5.0, 5.68, 1]
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can draw different color for different point like this in Echarts

```
const scatterData = data.map((p) => ({
      name: 'point',
      value: [p.xPos, p.yPos],
      itemStyle: p.color
    }));
```

Then in option:

```
option = {
  series:[
  {
    symbolSize: 20,
    data:scatterData, 
    type: 'scatter',
    ...
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Do I have to compute the colors manually? Is there no automated way to map a continuous dimension via a colormap like other plotting libraries do?

Answer (score 3):

One way to pull it off is the following:

Declare an `itemStyle` property in the corresponding object from the `series` array as follows:

```js
series: [
  ...,
  itemStyle: {
    color: function(param) {
      // Write your logic.
      // for example: in case your data is structured as an array of arrays, you can paint it red if the first value is lower than 10:
      if (param.data[0] < 10) return 'red'
      // Or if data is structured as an array of values:
      if (param[0] < 10) return 'red'
    }
  },
]
```